# pymongo.errors.DocumentTooLarge: 'aggregate' command document too large

Tags: python, pymongo

I aggregate data using pymongo, the data is about 10 millions, I use

```
df_list = mycol.aggregate([{'$match': {'tbl_id': {'$in': doc_list}}}, {'$project': {'_id': 0}}], allowDiskUse=True) # doc_list may be very large
```

to aggregate the data, but it still went wrong,`pymongo.errors.DocumentTooLarge: 'aggregate' command document too large`, the `allowDiskUse=True` cannot work for me. How to deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

Mongo documents cannot be larger than 16MBs. That means that your query object:

```
df_list = mycol.aggregate([{'$match': {'tbl_id': {'$in': doc_list}}}, {'$project': {'_id': 0}}], allowDiskUse=True) # doc_list may be very large
```

cannot be larger than 16MBs, you probably have a huge **doc_list** which exceeds the maximun allowed size. **allowDiskUse** option does nothing because the problem is prior to that.

You can split your query in multiples queries by batching your doc_list, is slower but it does the trick.